# Re-calibrating Intercept on logistic regression models for unbalance data

Tags: logistic, logit, odds-ratio, intercept, calibration

I have data-set that I’m modelling using logistic regression as land.cover~H1+H2+H3+H4+H6+H8+H14. My response and categorical variables are binary.  However the number of 0 and 1 in my response variable are very disproportionate, 0 = 18217207 and 1= 206504. Following the advice of this blog: http://r-statistics.co/Logistic-Regression-With-R.html, I decided to balance these proportions in the training and test data, to assure that the logit model works.  The main issue with that is that the intercept of my model changes.

I want to transform the coefficients ( log odd ratio) to probabilities using this formula, where  β0 is the intercept and  βx are the coefficients.

p= exp(β0 + β1*x1 + … + βk*xk)/(1+exp(β0 + β1*x1 + … + βk*xk))

For that, I need to recalibrate my intercept to represent the real prevalence of the land cover.  Do you know any methodology to do that?

I leave a piece of my code where I show the balance of 0 and 1 in the training data.

```
         > data.model.200
              land.cover H1 H2 H3 H4 H6 H8 H14
           1:          0  1  0  0  0  0  0   1
           2:          0  1  0  0  0  0  0   1
           3:          1  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
           4:          0  1  0  0  0  0  0   1
           5:          1  1  1  0  0  0  0   1      
    ---                                 
    18423707:          0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0
    18423708:          0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0
    18423709:          0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0
    18423710:          0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0
    18423711:          0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0
> table(data.model.200$land.cover)
       0        1 
18217207   206504

# Create Training Data
input_ones <- data.model.200[which(data.model.200$land.cover == 1), ]  # all 1's
input_zeros <- data.model.200[which(data.model.200$land.cover == 0), ]  # all 0's
set.seed(100)  # for repeatability of samples
input_ones_training_rows <- sample(1:nrow(input_ones), 0.7*nrow(input_ones))  # 1's for training
input_zeros_training_rows <- sample(1:nrow(input_zeros), 0.7*nrow(input_ones))  # 0's for training. Pick as many 0's as 1's
training_ones <- input_ones[input_ones_training_rows, ]  
training_zeros <- input_zeros[input_zeros_training_rows, ]
trainingData <- rbind(training_ones, training_zeros)  # row bind the 1's and 0's 

# Create Test Data
test_ones <- input_ones[-input_ones_training_rows, ]
test_zeros <- input_zeros[-input_zeros_training_rows, ]
testData <- rbind(test_ones, test_zeros)  # row bind the 1's and 0's 


# Bulding the model

logitMod <- glm(land.cover ~ H1 + H2 + H3 + H4 + H6 + H8 + H14, data=trainingData, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

Comment: Logistic regression does not require balancing to “work”.

Answer (score 2):

Logistic regression is a probability model.  Probabilities are only really interesting if they differ from 0.5, so "imbalance" is expected and is of no consequence.  Logistic regression can handle extreme degrees of imbalance and still provide trustworthy estimates of conditional probabilities.   The idea that you need to delete some of the sample in order to fit the model violates statistical principles and is inefficient at best.  Samples are too precious to waste.  All that's required of successful logistic modeling is a certain absolute frequency in each of the Y categories (ignore relative frequency).

Think of it this way: if you try to balance the sample in some way your analysis will not apply to any future dataset.  The intercept of the model will be ruined.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here you are facing is of probability calibration. You have an unbalanced dataset and you have used either upsampling/downsampling to help the model train/learn better. However, the probability you are getting is of a landscape where both can happen equally likely since you changed the distribution. To fix the probabilities by capturing the true distribution of 0 & 1 we can use the formula
You just have to correct your predicted probability p_s using the following formula:

```
actual_prob = (X * pred_prob)/( (X-1) * pred_prob + 1 )
```

where X is the ratio of the number of majority class data points after downsampling over the number majority class data points in the starting training set ( without any pre-processing ).

[For Reference](https://www3.nd.edu/~rjohns15/content/papers/ssci2015_calibrating.pdf)